# Parsing a file by blocks and extracting information from each of the blocks with Python

Tags: python, list, parsing, coordinates, vrml

I'm trying to parse some blocks of text in a vrml file. Specifically I'm interested in the information contained in the IndexedFaceSets which represents a series of triangles defined by its coordinate points (field Points) and the conectivity between the points (field coordIndex).

I have managed to create a function that parses a single indexedFaceSet (the first one) of text but I cannot get my head around as to how to modify the code so I can store the following list `[translate,verts,facets,normals]` for each IndexedFaceSet.

My function is:

```
def extractDataFromVRML(root):
    #Lists to be populated
    translate=[]
    verts=[]
    facets=[]
    normals=[]
    #Parsing the vrml file
    f=open(root+'.wrl')
    while 1:# skip through initial stuff
      linney=str.split(f.readline())
    # print linney
      if len(linney) == 4:
        if linney[0] == 'translation': #Not shown in th vrml example
          transx = float(linney[1])
          transy = float(linney[2])
          transz = float(linney[3])
          t=[transx,transy,transz]
          translate.append(t)
      if linney == ['point', '[']:
        break
    #print 'Reading vertex coordinates.'
    while 1:
      xyz = f.readline()
      i = str.find(xyz,',')
      if i < 0:    # end of vertex coordinates
        break
      verts.append(xyz[:i]) # building a list of xyz strings
    print ('We have',len(verts)-1,'vertices.')
    #for v in verts: print v
    print ('Reading triangles.')
    while 1:
      linney=f.readline()
      if linney == '}\n':
        break     # end of file
      abc = str.split(str.replace(linney,',',' ')) # l of vertex ids
      if len(abc) < 3:
        continue   # separation between groups of triangles
      # look up a vertex in the list to generate a triangle tuple
      xyz = str.split(verts[int(abc[0])])
      p1=[float(xyz[0]),float(xyz[1]),float(xyz[2])]     
      xyz = str.split(verts[int(abc[1])])
      p2=[float(xyz[0]),float(xyz[1]),float(xyz[2])]     
      xyz = str.split(verts[int(abc[2])])
      p3=[float(xyz[0]),float(xyz[1]),float(xyz[2])]     
      tri=[p1,p2,p3]
      facets.append(tri)
      #n=getNormals(p1[0],p1[1],p1[2],p2[0],p2[1],p2[2],p3[0],p3[1],p3[2])
      #normals.append(n)
    print ('END')
    return [translate,verts,facets,normals]
```

An example of a cube in vrml is as follows:

```
#VRML V2.0 utf8

WorldInfo {
    info [ "File created using CATIA" ]
}
NavigationInfo {
    type [ "EXAMINE" , "WALK" , "FLY" ]
}
Background {
    skyColor [ 1 1 1 ]
}
Viewpoint {
    position      0.411502 0.183945 0.216403
    orientation   0.326678 0.502925 0.800218 2.185925
    fieldOfView   0.471225
    description   "Main Viewpoint"
}
Viewpoint {
    position      0.288675 0.288675 0.288675
    orientation   0.187053 0.451587 0.872399 2.448076
    fieldOfView   0.471225
    description   "Iso View"
}
Viewpoint {
    position      0.500000 0.000000 0.000000
    orientation   0.577350 0.577350 0.577350 2.094395
    fieldOfView   0.471225
    description   "Front View"
}
Viewpoint {
    position      -0.500000 0.000000 0.000000
    orientation   0.577350 -0.577350 -0.577350 2.094395
    fieldOfView   0.471225
    description   "Back View"
}
Viewpoint {
    position      0.000000 -0.500000 0.000000
    orientation   1.000000 -0.000173 0.000173 1.570796
    fieldOfView   0.471225
    description   "Left View"
}
Viewpoint {
    position      0.000000 0.500000 0.000000
    orientation   -0.000122 -0.707107 -0.707107 3.141348
    fieldOfView   0.471225
    description   "Right View"
}
Viewpoint {
    position      0.000000 0.000000 0.500000
    orientation   0.000000 0.000000 1.000000 1.570796
    fieldOfView   0.471225
    description   "Top View"
}
Viewpoint {
    position      0.000000 0.000000 -0.500000
    orientation   0.707107 0.707107 0.000000 3.141593
    fieldOfView   0.471225
    description   "Bottom View"
}
Transform {
    scale         0.001 0.001 0.001
    children [
Group {
    children [
Group {
    children [
DEF _000000002346A9A0 Group {
    children [
    ]
}
    ]
}
Group {
    children [
DEF _0000000023470B20 Group {
    children [
    ]
}
    ]
}
Group {
    children [
DEF _00000000234700D0 Group {
    children [
    ]
}
    ]
}
Group {
    children [
Group {
    children [
DEF _0000000020D0F390 Group {
    children [
Shape {
appearance Appearance {
    material DEF _material0 Material {
        diffuseColor  0.823529 0.823529 1
    }
}
geometry IndexedFaceSet {
solid FALSE
coord Coordinate {
    point   [
         0 50 50,
         50 50 50,
         50 0 50,
         0 0 50,
        ]
    }
coordIndex [
 3,2,0,-1,
 2,1,0,-1,
]

}
}
Shape {
appearance Appearance {
material USE _material0
}
geometry IndexedFaceSet {
solid FALSE
coord Coordinate {
    point   [
         0 50 0,
         50 50 0,
         50 0 0,
         0 0 0,
        ]
    }
coordIndex [
 3,0,2,-1,
 0,1,2,-1,
]

}
}
Shape {
appearance Appearance {
material USE _material0
}
geometry IndexedFaceSet {
solid FALSE
coord Coordinate {
    point   [
         0 0 50,
         0 0 0,
         0 50 0,
         0 50 50,
        ]
    }
coordIndex [
 2,1,3,-1,
 1,0,3,-1,
]

}
}
Shape {
appearance Appearance {
material USE _material0
}
geometry IndexedFaceSet {
solid FALSE
coord Coordinate {
    point   [
         0 50 50,
         0 50 0,
         50 50 0,
         50 50 50,
        ]
    }
coordIndex [
 2,1,3,-1,
 1,0,3,-1,
]

}
}
Shape {
appearance Appearance {
material USE _material0
}
geometry IndexedFaceSet {
solid FALSE
coord Coordinate {
    point   [
         50 50 50,
         50 50 0,
         50 0 0,
         50 0 50,
        ]
    }
coordIndex [
 2,1,3,-1,
 1,0,3,-1,
]

}
}
Shape {
appearance Appearance {
material USE _material0
}
geometry IndexedFaceSet {
solid FALSE
coord Coordinate {
    point   [
         50 0 50,
         50 0 0,
         0 0 0,
         0 0 50,
        ]
    }
coordIndex [
 2,1,3,-1,
 1,0,3,-1,
]

}
}
    ]
}
    ]
}
    ]
}
    ]
}
    ]
}
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Expected output is ideally a dictionary with  keys 'IndexedFaceSet 1,2,3...' and the corresponding data i.e [translate,verts,facets,normals] associated to each face (the ouput of the current function given, which works only for the first IndexedFaceSet at the moment).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a non-trivial parsing problem. If you can find some Python package for parsing, it would be best. Here is my approach: scan the file, line by line. If I see something I understand, then pass the remaining lines to the parser for that block. For example, I have parser to parse the block that starts with the line "geometry IndexedFaceSet".

```
import itertools
import json
import logging
from pprint import pprint
import os

# For the next line, use logging.WARN to turn off debug print, use
# logging.DEBUG to turn on
logging.basicConfig(level=os.getenv('LOGLEVEL', logging.WARN))
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def skip_pass(marker, lines):
    """
    Skip until reach the line which contains the marker, then also skip
    the marker line
    """
    result = itertools.dropwhile(
        lambda line: marker not in line,  # Condition
        lines)                            # The lines
    next(result)                          # skip pass the marker
    return result

def take(marker, lines):
    """
    Take and return those lines which contains a marker
    """
    result = itertools.takewhile(
        lambda line: marker in line,      # Condition
        lines)                            # The lines
    return result

def parse_indexed_face_set(translate, lines):
    """
    Parse one block of 'geometry IndexedFaceSet'
    """
    # lines = skip_pass('geometry IndexedFaceSet', lines)

    # Parse the "point" structure
    lines = skip_pass('point', lines)
    point_lines = take(',', lines)
    verts = [[float(token) for token in line.strip(',\n').split()] for line in point_lines]
    logger.debug('verts: %r', verts)

    # parse the coordIndex structure
    lines = skip_pass('coordIndex', lines)
    coor_lines = take(',', lines)
    coord_index = [tuple(int(token) for token in line.strip(',\n').split(',')) for line in coor_lines]
    logger.debug('coord_index: %r', coord_index)

    facets = [[verts[i] for i in indices[:3]] for indices in coord_index]
    logger.debug('facets: %r', facets)

    return dict(vert=verts, facets=facets, translate=translate, normals=[])

def parse_translate(line):
    """
    Given a line such as: "translate 5 6 7", return [5.0, 6.0, 7.0]
    """
    translate = [float(x) for x in line.split()[1:4]]
    return translate

def extractDataFromVRML(root):
    indexed_face_sets = []
    translate = []
    with open(root + '.wrl') as infile:
        for line in infile:
            if 'geometry IndexedFaceSet' in line:
                a_set = parse_indexed_face_set(translate=translate, lines=infile)
                indexed_face_sets.append(a_set)
            elif 'translation' in line and line.split()[0] == 'translation':
                translate = parse_translate(line)

    return indexed_face_sets


# main
indexed_face_sets = extractDataFromVRML('root')
for a_set in indexed_face_sets:
    print('vert:', a_set['vert'])
    print('facets:', a_set['facets'])
    print('---')
```

## Output

```
vert: [[0.0, 50.0, 50.0], [50.0, 50.0, 50.0], [50.0, 0.0, 50.0], [0.0, 0.0, 50.0]]
facets: [[[0.0, 0.0, 50.0], [50.0, 0.0, 50.0], [0.0, 50.0, 50.0]], [[50.0, 0.0, 50.0], [50.0, 50.0, 50.0], [0.0, 50.0, 50.0]]]
---
vert: [[0.0, 50.0, 0.0], [50.0, 50.0, 0.0], [50.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]
facets: [[[0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 50.0, 0.0], [50.0, 0.0, 0.0]], [[0.0, 50.0, 0.0], [50.0, 50.0, 0.0], [50.0, 0.0, 0.0]]]
---
vert: [[0.0, 0.0, 50.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 50.0, 0.0], [0.0, 50.0, 50.0]]
facets: [[[0.0, 50.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 50.0, 50.0]], [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 50.0], [0.0, 50.0, 50.0]]]
---
vert: [[0.0, 50.0, 50.0], [0.0, 50.0, 0.0], [50.0, 50.0, 0.0], [50.0, 50.0, 50.0]]
facets: [[[50.0, 50.0, 0.0], [0.0, 50.0, 0.0], [50.0, 50.0, 50.0]], [[0.0, 50.0, 0.0], [0.0, 50.0, 50.0], [50.0, 50.0, 50.0]]]
---
vert: [[50.0, 50.0, 50.0], [50.0, 50.0, 0.0], [50.0, 0.0, 0.0], [50.0, 0.0, 50.0]]
facets: [[[50.0, 0.0, 0.0], [50.0, 50.0, 0.0], [50.0, 0.0, 50.0]], [[50.0, 50.0, 0.0], [50.0, 50.0, 50.0], [50.0, 0.0, 50.0]]]
---
vert: [[50.0, 0.0, 50.0], [50.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 50.0]]
facets: [[[0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [50.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 50.0]], [[50.0, 0.0, 0.0], [50.0, 0.0, 50.0], [0.0, 0.0, 50.0]]]
---
```

## Notes

- During development, I often need to print some values for debugging purpose. For that, I use the the logger object, created from the `logging` library
- I use the `itertools.takewhile()` and `itertools.dropwhile()` functions to simplify some of the tasks

Comment: Hai Vu, this is a brilliant piece of code, a much cleaner way than my previous attempt to tackle the problem! Thank you!